# Docker0 interface missing on WSL2

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I have installed Docker on WSL2 using following instruction: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/. However when I try to connect from container to host using information from this answer:

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), I am not able to do this.

I have noticed that there is no docker0 interface created on host:

```
earkjac@DESKTOP-U4U3IDU:~/repo/platform_health_managment$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4e:26:e9:f0:62:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:2f:38:0c:fc:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:5c:37:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.252.58/20 brd 172.22.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5c:3730/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

How to create this interafce ? Should be this done automatically ?

Comment: The simplest answer to the canonical question you link to is to use the `host.docker.internal` host name when it exists.  Is that an option here?